# X509: certfificate signed by unknown authority when using docker login from a remote machine

Tags: docker, ssl, centos, ssl-certificate, nexus3

I’m trying to acces a private nexus repo. using docker login from a remote machine on the same network and despite i have followed instuctions in the documentation of docker i still get the **x509: certfificate signed by unknown authority** error,
I’m on a **centOs 8** machine, with nexus **OSS 3.29.2-02**, i’ve configured the the repo according to the following documentation [Configuring SSL](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/system-configuration/configuring-ssl#ConfiguringSSL-InboundSSL-ConfiguringtoServeContentviaHTTPS)
and i’ve created the self signed certificate using java keytool and it works when i access it from the browser on the same machine and from the remote machine, in the **/app/sonatype-work/nexus3/log/nexus.log** log file there is no errors.
i’ve copied the certificate .cer to the **/etc/docker/certs.d/domain:port/** location then i also copied it to **/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/** and ran **sudo update-ca-trust** according to docker docs:
[docker insecure registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/)
when i **keytool -printcert -sslserver domain:port -v** from the remote machine the certificate is printed.
when i wget from the remote machine it works and the certificate is successfully validated and data downloaded.
i’ve checked many topics but all are talking about putting the certificate in the above mentioned locations what i’ve already done.
thanks in advance.

----------------------update--------------------------

```
[mehdilapin@localhost ~]$ wget https://mycustomregistry.com:7575
--2021-04-11 14:53:59--  https://mycustomregistry.com:7575/
Auflösen des Hostnamens mycustomregistry.com (mycustomregistry.com)… 192.168.1.9
Verbindungsaufbau zu mycustomregistry.com (mycustomregistry.com)|192.168.1.9|:7575 … verbunden.
HTTP-Anforderung gesendet, auf Antwort wird gewartet … 200 OK
Länge: 8903 (8,7K) [text/html]
Wird in »index.html.2« gespeichert.

index.html.2                                         100%[=====================================================================================================================>]   8,69K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2021-04-11 14:53:59 (287 MB/s) - »index.html.2« gespeichert [8903/8903]

[mehdilapin@localhost ~]$ sudo keytool -printcert -sslserver mycustomregistry.com:4563/registry/api -v
Certificate #0
====================================
Eigentümer: CN=mycustomregistry.com, OU=organization Unit, O=organization, L=USA, ST=NewYork, C=US
Aussteller: CN=mycustomregistry.com, OU=organization Unit, O=organization, L=USA, ST=NewYork, C=US
Seriennummer: 68e917a2
Gültig von: Sun Apr 11 14:34:54 CET 2021 bis: Mon Apr 11 14:34:54 CET 2022
Zertifikatsfingerprints:
     SHA1: 05:95:71:99:93:D1:30:A0:D1:82:0C:73:61:47:69:F0:2A:A4:52:B3
     SHA256: EA:8A:0A:0C:C6:4B:BE:73:57:78:CC:DC:08:DE:92:8E:04:6F:B8:3E:8F:2A:71:C8:AD:5A:E7:19:BB:31:7C:AE
Signaturalgorithmusname: SHA256withRSA
Public Key-Algorithmus von Subject: 2048-Bit-RSA-Schlüssel
Version: 3

Erweiterungen: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: EF C5 91 38 62 ED 54 12   4E AA 9C 0F C6 73 F2 0C  ...8b.T.N....s..
0010: 83 BF CA 5E                                        ...^
]
]

[mehdilapin@localhost ~]$ sudo keytool -printcert -file /etc/docker/certs.d/mycustomregistry.com\:4563/ca-certificate.cer 
Eigentümer: CN=mycustomregistry.com, OU=organization Unit, O=organization, L=USA, ST=NewYork, C=US
Aussteller: CN=mycustomregistry.com, OU=organization Unit, O=organization, L=USA, ST=NewYork, C=US
Seriennummer: 68e917a2
Gültig von: Sun Apr 11 14:34:54 CET 2021 bis: Mon Apr 11 14:34:54 CET 2022
Zertifikatsfingerprints:
     SHA1: 05:95:71:99:93:D1:30:A0:D1:82:0C:73:61:47:69:F0:2A:A4:52:B3
     SHA256: EA:8A:0A:0C:C6:4B:BE:73:57:78:CC:DC:08:DE:92:8E:04:6F:B8:3E:8F:2A:71:C8:AD:5A:E7:19:BB:31:7C:AE
Signaturalgorithmusname: SHA256withRSA
Public Key-Algorithmus von Subject: 2048-Bit-RSA-Schlüssel
Version: 3

Erweiterungen: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: EF C5 91 38 62 ED 54 12   4E AA 9C 0F C6 73 F2 0C  ...8b.T.N....s..
0010: 83 BF CA 5E                                        ...^
]
]


[mehdilapin@localhost ~]$ sudo keytool -printcert -file /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/ca-certificate.cer -v
Eigentümer: CN=mycustomregistry.com, OU=organization Unit, O=organization, L=USA, ST=NewYork, C=US
Aussteller: CN=mycustomregistry.com, OU=organization Unit, O=organization, L=USA, ST=NewYork, C=US
Seriennummer: 68e917a2
Gültig von: Sun Apr 11 14:34:54 CET 2021 bis: Mon Apr 11 14:34:54 CET 2022
Zertifikatsfingerprints:
     SHA1: 05:95:71:99:93:D1:30:A0:D1:82:0C:73:61:47:69:F0:2A:A4:52:B3
     SHA256: EA:8A:0A:0C:C6:4B:BE:73:57:78:CC:DC:08:DE:92:8E:04:6F:B8:3E:8F:2A:71:C8:AD:5A:E7:19:BB:31:7C:AE
Signaturalgorithmusname: SHA256withRSA
Public Key-Algorithmus von Subject: 2048-Bit-RSA-Schlüssel
Version: 3

Erweiterungen: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: EF C5 91 38 62 ED 54 12   4E AA 9C 0F C6 73 F2 0C  ...8b.T.N....s..
0010: 83 BF CA 5E                                        ...^
]
]
```

Comment: Have you restarted the docker engine since updating certificates on the host?

Comment: Yes several times.

Comment: Please include commands run, and output from those commands, to reproduce the issue. E.g. don't just say you copied a certificate to a folder, or that wget works, but show it.

Comment: please look, i've updated the post, the wget was done to port 7575 because to port 4563 i get a 400 bad request and it's normal because the nexus registry does accept only docker requests on this port and with the browser it's the same it says the request is not a docker request and it displays a 400 error, but the important is that when i display the certificate on port 4563 with keytool i get it. sorry my machine is in Germanic

Comment: and this is the docker login output
[mehdilapin@localhost ~]$ sudo docker login -u admin mycustomregistry.com:4563
Password: 
Error response from daemon: Get https://mycustomregistry.com:4563/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certificates in `/etc/docker/certs.d/` need to be x509 formatted and named with a crt extension (it's actually possible to configure client tls settings with this same folder). So rename:

```
/etc/docker/certs.d/mycustomregistry.com\:4563/ca-certificate.cer
```

to an x509/pem formatted certificate named:

```
/etc/docker/certs.d/mycustomregistry.com\:4563/ca-certificate.crt
```

That doesn't explain why the OS certificates aren't working. When checking with wget and curl, you should be able to reach the v2 api, even if it gives you a permission denied error:

```
curl https://mycustomregistry.com:4563/v2/
```

Comment: yesterday i tried to generate a .crt format certificate using keytool and doesn't work now i tried the command sudo openssl x509 -inform der -in /etc/docker/certs.d/mycustomregistry.com\:4563/ca-certificate.cer -out ca.crt and it works, it's really hard to manage all these format type, for the os level it has always work as i told you when i wget to the 4563 port i get a 400 error and not a certificate error, i tried to remove the certificate from the anchors folder and i got instead a unknown certificate authority error, Thank you very much.

Comment: @ben624 hitting the `/v2/` endpoint should give you a 401 rather 400 error, or a 200 if there's no required auth. The registry api spec is documented here: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/

Comment: Yes you are right, i did it to /V2/ and got 401, earlier i was hitting only mycustomregistry.com:4563 without the V2, the v2 is added automatically when using docker login but with wget it's not added.